# Mongodb: how to load data after it's been saved?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

How to load all of the documents within a database right after a new document has been added to the database?

```
app.get('/ajax', function(req, res) {

    var itemOne = new Todo({item: req.query.item}).save(function(err,data){
        if (err) throw err;
    });

    Todo.find({}, function(err1, data1){
        if (err1) throw err;
        res.send(data1);
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. You have code shown. What's the issue? Also - is it *really* your intent to load and return an *entire collection*?

Answer (score 0):

```
app.get('/ajax', function(req, res) {

var itemOne = new Todo({item: req.query.item}).save(function(err,data){
    if (err) throw err; //Find Records right here

    Todo.find({}, function(err1, data1){
    if (err1) throw err;
    res.send(data1);
   }); 
});});
```

In your code "save" function and "find" function will run asynchronously so finding inside the callback function will get u all the results